# GAE app working locally but not when uploaded to google's servers

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine

So I have this google app engine app that a development company developed and they put a test server up online and it works completely.  I can build the app locally and run it on the gae dev server locally and everything works, but when I upload to google app engine it gets errors and 404 page not found. I fixed all the errors by including specific .jar files in the WEB-INF/lib directory that I found in target/lib.

I've tried just including all the .jar files that are in the target/lib directory but then the app gets errors locally so I've had to find the specific files and include those in the WEB-INF/lib directory.

In the logs I get this error

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound: No mapping found
 for HTTP request with URI [/api/universe/v1/auth/signup/student/email] in DispatcherServlet 
with name 'spring-dispatcher'
```

For this error I can't find which file may be missing that I need to include in the WEB-INF/lib directory because I have already included all of the spring .jar files. What file may I be missing?  Is there anything else I should include in here to help find what the problem is?

Also if there a way to see what files are being uploaded to google app engine? If I could just see what was missing I could stick it into the WEB-INF/lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message indicates that there's a servlet-mapping element missing and/or improperly set up for the DispatcherServlet ('spring-dispatcher' could either be a param-name or the actual servlet-name, without your web.xml file I cannot say for certain). You can set the servlet-mapping element in the web.xml file in WEB-INF.

As an example, a given servlet could be set up like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>redteam</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mysite.server.TeamServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>redteam</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/red/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

There's documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml) for more information on the web.xml file